# Parse such a String into a object structure using Java (GWT)

Tags: java, parsing

I am trying to parse an string in GWT to an Object structure. Unfortunately I am not able to do it.

Example string:

```
"(node1(node2(node3) (node4)) (node5))"
```

- `"node1"` has 2 children: `"node2"` and `"node5"`
- `"node2"` has 2 children: `"node3"` and `"node4"`

Object can be "node", with children.
Any help on this will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This has nothing to do with GWT.

Comment: @Amadan, true, but I guess the OP wants to end up with a JavaScript object (associative array) and then the question would become: *"how would I do it in Java (so that the GWT compiler produces a JS-object)"*, in which case the GWT is relevant.

Comment: @user1241200, why are you "thinking" about it in JS terms? You should code it all in plain Java, and shouldn't worry how the GWT compiler translates this into JS.

Comment: Sure, but then it would be best built in JavaScript, not Java - you'd lose some of the strong typing that is most of the point of using Java/GWT in the first place... But if building this in GWT or Java (or javascript), it should mostly be the same - parse the string, building a tree-like object, using a stack to keep track of position in the tree - pushing on "(" and popping on ")". More info on 'what have you tried' would be good from the asker - "Unfortunately I am not able to do it" doesn't quite cover that.

Comment: @Amadan You are right it has nothing to do with GWT. My apologies.

Comment: @ColinAlworth Thanks for pointing out in the right direction and I should have provided with what I have tried. This is my first post will make sure to include what I've tried from next one.

Comment: @BartKiers I did finally code it in plain JAVA. I was thinking more interms of passing a string to JSNI and getting JSO out of it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can provide you with a pseudo-code. I believe the following algorithm will work but please let me know if you spot anything wrong with it.

```
Create a root node called nodeRoot.
current_node = nodeRoot
For each char in the string:
    if the char is '('
        add a child node to current_node
        parse the string (after the '(' char) to fetch the name of the node
        current_node = the newly added child node
    else if the char is ')'
        current_node = parent of current_node
```

To keep track of parents, you can use a stack.

Comment: In Java, you can use `StringTokenizer(str, "()", true)` to avoid going character by character. You can also use recursion (implicit stack) to keep track of parents a bit easier.

Comment: @Amadan - +1 for the mention of StringTokenizer. However one should keep in mind that it's a legacy class.

Comment: And since the asker is looking for use in GWT, worth pointing out that StringTokenizer isn't emulated in GWT, see http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/RefJreEmulation.html

Comment: Eh dang :) So it apparently *does* have something to do with GWT. I stand corrected.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty bored so I knocked together some code.

```
  private static class ObjectTree {
    private Set<ObjectTree> children = new LinkedHashSet();
    private ObjectTree parent = null;
    private String text = null;
    private int level = 0;

    public ObjectTree() {
      this(null);
    }

    public ObjectTree(ObjectTree parent) {
      this(parent, 0);
    }

    public ObjectTree(ObjectTree parent, int level) {
      this.parent = parent;
      this.level = level;
    }

    public void addChild(ObjectTree child) {
      children.add(child);
    }

    public void parse(String s) {
      int ix = s.indexOf("(");
      if (ix > 0)
        text = s.substring(0, ix);
      else if (ix <= 0)
        text = s;
      int iy = ix + 1;
      int count = 1;
      if (ix == -1)
        return;
      while (iy < s.length()) {
        if (s.charAt(iy) == ')')
          count--;
        else if (s.charAt(iy) == '(')
          count++;
        if (count == 0) {
          String newString = s.substring(ix + 1, iy);
          ObjectTree newChild = new ObjectTree(this, level + 1);
          addChild(newChild);
          newChild.parse(newString);
          ix = s.indexOf('(', iy);
          count++;
          iy = ix;
        }
        iy++;
      }

    }

    public String toString() {
      StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
      sb.append(StringUtils.repeat("\t.", level)).append(text).append(" :\n");
      for (ObjectTree child : children) {
        sb.append(StringUtils.repeat("\t", level)).append("\t").append(child.toString()).append("\n");
      }
      if (!children.isEmpty())
        sb.append("\n");
      return sb.toString();
    }

  }
```

You call it like so:

```
ObjectTree root = new ObjectTree();
root.parse("(node1(node2(node3) (node4)) (node5))");
System.out.println(root.toString());
```

And get:

```
(node1(node2(node3) (node4)) (node5)) :
    .node1 :
        .   .node2 :
            .   .   .node3 :
            .   .   .node4 :
        .   .node5 :
```